# dynamically generate different google map

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

HI i was wondering how am i suppose to generate multiple google map based on different lat and long

what i mean is one pair of lat and long will plot on individual map

My json string is below as u can see there is two pair of lat and long what i want to achieve is being able to show two different map using javascript

```
[{"ID":"14","deviceID":"00000000-2b3a-8361-200f-007926c98c48","lat":"1.3471443","lng":"103.9598796","Message":"Panic Button was activated!","DateTimes":"11/29/2014 12:00:00 AM","deviceName":"Nexus 5"},{"ID":"16","deviceID":"00000000-2b3a-8361-200f-007926c98c48","lat":"1.3471514","lng":"103.9598849","Message":"Panic Button was activated!","DateTimes":"11/30/2014 12:58:37 AM","deviceName":"Nexus 5"}]
```

Currently i have this code and its giving me this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

`

```
  for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {    

                        function initialize(lat,lng) {
                        //latLng = latLng.split(",")
                        var mapOptions = {
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                            zoom: 8
                        };
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('canvas_'+obj[i].ID), mapOptions);
                        }


                        var element = document.getElementById("inline_content");

                        var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
                        h3.innerHTML = obj[i].DateTimes ;

                          ifrm = document.createElement('canvas_'+obj[i].ID); 

                           element.appendChild(ifrm); 
                        element.appendChild(h3);
                        initialize(obj[i].lat,+obj[i].lng);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using document.createElement wrong.  First you have to say what tag it will be; in your case a div.

```
...
h3.innerHTML = obj[i].DateTimes ;
// create element.
ifrm = document.createElement('div');           // we make a <div>
ifrm.setAttribute('id', 'canvas_' + obj[i].ID); // set the id of the <div>
ifrm.setAttribute('class', 'map');  // so we can style the map elements ( class="map" ).
element.appendChild(ifrm); 
element.appendChild(h3);
...
```